# SQL code guidance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've recently had to start using SQL, and am struggling a little with how to code some more advanced capabilities etc, so was hoping for some guidance.

I have one database that contains high level data split by geography, NAICS industry and size of company, with field names such as:

```
CBSACODE  VERTICAL      COMPANYSIZE     DEVICES   
01010     Agriculture   1-10            100
01010     Education     20-99           50
01010     Healthcare    200-499         250
01010     Manufacturing 100-199         150
01010     Manufacturing 1-10            80
78910     Agriculture   1-10            25
78910     Government    500+            400
78910     Agriculture   11-19           60
78910     Finance       100-199         310
78910     Retail        20-99           200
```

I have a second database which is at a customer level but has some overlapping fields

```
CUSTOMER NAME   VERTICAL       COMPANYSIZE   ZIPCODE     CBSACODE
Customer A      Agriculture    1-10           12345       78910
Customer B      Manufacturing  100-199        54321       01010
```

What I am trying to do is to display the list of customers, and then display the sum of 'Number of devices' based on matching the CBSA Code, Vertical Industry and Company Size for each customer against the first database.

```
CUSTOMER NAME  CBSADEVICES   CBSA+VERTICALDEVICES    COSIZEDEVICES
Customer A     995           85                      25
Customer B     630           230                     150
```

I started trying to write a query using SUM and CASE WHEN etc but quickly got overwhelmed.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2016 (Express).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.....I've read through a number of various threads, but have yet to get my head around it sadly.

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: We can't even pretend to offer any help at this point because we have absolutely no information. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: Make sure to use real quantity between the source table and the outcome table, sometimes it helps to convey what you want to do.